# Unable to login to SonicWall TZ 215 after firmware upgrade

Tags: networking, firewall, dell, sonicwall

After upgrading the SonicWalls firmware from 5.8 to 5.9.1.7 and attempting to login I'm told that the password is not secure enough and that it must be changed before I can proceed.

The problem is each time I try to set a new password it tells me it does not meet the criteria.

[image]

However the passwords I am using match those criteria but they are still rejected, so I'm currently locked out of the SonicWall

Is there anyway to get around this other than a factory reset?

Comment: Try with a 12-chars password with lower and upper case, two numbers and a special char (as @). Does that change anything?

Comment: @shodanshok That actually fixed it, thank you very much! Is this documented anywhere online?

Comment: I don't know if it is documented, but such a password should be sufficiently complex to satisfy any default password complexity level. I'll write an answer; please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As show in the comment section, a **12-chars password with lower and upper case, two numbers and a special char** (as @) did the trick.